# android webview timeout error callback

Tags: android, webview

These are the callback I have for the WebView, but none of them returns me a TimeOut Error, is there any other I can add in order to get them?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            webViewError = true;
            errorMessageView.setText(getString(R.string.unknown_error) + " " + error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            webViewError = true;
            errorMessageView.setText(getString(R.string.unknown_error) + " " + errorResponse.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            webViewError = true;
            errorMessageView.setText(getString(R.string.ssl_error));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            setUpView();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)` you have used will get called only if the device has Android M.

To support other versions, you have to use the deprecated `onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)`.

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    //Handle the error
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr){
    onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
}
```